# Tweepy unauthorized 401 error when Retweeting

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I'm building a Twitter bot using Tweepy. When I'm testing it, I try to Retweet a test mention that I did, but I get an unauthorized 401 error. When getting timeline informations or just printing the mention ID/content, everything is fine, but when I try to retweet it, it raises 401:

I also changed my app permissions to write and read the first time I got the error.

```py
import tweepy

consumer_key = '##########'
consumer_secret = '#######'
acess_token = '##'
acess_token_secret = '#'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(acess_token, acess_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

mentions = api.mentions_timeline()
for mention in mentions:
    api.retweet(mention.id)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lorenzo\desktop\twitter-bot\open-source-divulgator-bot\app.py", line 15, in <module>
    api.retweet(mention.id)
  File "C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\twitter-bot\open-source-divulgator-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\twitter-bot\open-source-divulgator-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 993, in retweet
    return self.request(
  File "C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\twitter-bot\open-source-divulgator-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 257, in request
    raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: Does your app have write permission?

Comment: Yes, good to remember, I changed it the first time i got the error, but still get it

Comment: Did you regenerate and use new credentials afterwards?

Comment: nope, didn't know i have to, i'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a common question and the solution is usually to grant the write permission and regenerate and use new credentials, like in this case, [I've added](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/f255866ff3b4bdd15632beaac0eecd067b8265e4) an [FAQ](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/faq.html) to Tweepy's documentation with [a section answering this question](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error).

Answer (score 3):

Doing what @Harmon758 said, I was able to run the code doing a simple regeneration on my credentials in the twitter developers site.

Comment: This is a definitely an answer. The author is self-answering the question based on help from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answers above and provide additional guidance.

**Step 1** - First verify that you are using `OAuthHandler` and not `AppAuthHandler`.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
```

**Step 2** - Within Twitter's [Developer portal](https://developer.twitter.com/) navigate to your project and verify that the App's permissions are set to either `Read and write` or `Read and write and Direct message` as displayed in the image below.

[image]

**Step 3** - You must regenerate new API Key and Secret and Access Token and Secret. Once the new keys are generated, make sure to update it either in your settings or code.

[image]

**Additional References**

- [Tweepy FAQ - Why am I encountering a 401 Unauthorized error?](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error)
- [Twitter Apps - App Permissions](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/app-permissions)